# Switching from a 2D vector into a 1D vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdvector

I have heard that a vector of vectors is bad in terms of performance. For example, I have the following 2D `std::vector`:

```
std::vector< std::vector<char> > characterMatrix;

// for iterating
for ( int row = 0; row < getY_AxisLen( ); ++row )
{
    for ( int column = 0; column < getX_AxisLen( ); ++column )
    {
        std::cout << characterMatrix[ row ][ column ];
    }
}
```

In this approach, the matrix gets printed in 3-12 milliseconds on my system. I would be glad if I saw a decrease of e.g. 1-3 milliseconds.

As far as I know, each of the internal vectors (i.e. *rows*) is stored in a different location on the heap memory. So this causes lots of fragmentation.
Not only that but the `sizeof(std::vector)` in my compiler returns 24 (bytes). So this means that for instance if `characterMatrix` has 50 rows (aka internal vectors) then it'll allocate **24*50 == 1200** bytes on the heap just to store the control blocks of those 50 vectors and this is in addition to the space taken by the actual data (`char`s) in the matrix.

Now if I want to keep all the `char`s in a single contiguous block of memory maybe I can write it as a 1D vector like:

```
std::vector< char > characterMatrix;

// for iterating
for ( int row = 0; row < getY_AxisLen( ); ++row )
{
    for ( int column = 0; column < getX_AxisLen( ); ++column )
    {
        std::cout << characterMatrix[ row * getX_AxisLen( ) + column ]; // is this correct?
    }
}
```

Is this a valid way of doing it? Can someone tell me what things should I keep in mind if I want to change the implementation of my matrix variable in such a way? What are the possible downsides?

Comment: I have "heard" that one should measure, profile and benchmark (an optimized build) before making decisions.

Comment: nitpick: the inner vectors are stored contiguously as elements of the outer, but your line of reasoning is correct, because the inner vectors store elements on the heap, such that elements of the matrix are not contiguous

Comment: Performance depends on many things, and should always be measured! Optimization often comes at the cost of readability/maintainability so like al engineering its a tradeof. But yes vectors of vectors can result in data that's a bit more scattered in memory then contiguous allocation and thus you won't make full use of cache (prediction). Maybe you've heard if's are bad too (branch prediction)... so what is your actual problem?

Comment: It depends. For example if you resize rows often then a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` might even perform better than a `std::vector<char>`. For sparse matrices you might consider a `std::map<index,int>`. As others have said, the only way to know is to measure

Comment: Whereas mostly each questions with usage of 2D leads to comment as 1D is better, funny to see that for this question, it is more measured :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't quite understand what you said.

Comment: *I have heard that a vector of vectors is bad in terms of performance*: it depends on the usage and requirements. But anyway, if you are at that kind of performance question, only assembly language should be an option, or at most, low level C, but you should forget about the C++ template library...

Comment: @digito_evo: It is just that most comments I saw on other questions is similar to *"use 1D vector for your matrix"* without other considerations even for beginners :-(. Here you got *"measure first"*, *"is it the bottleneck?"*, *"is it more readable"*? That amuses me.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta No I'm not writing a performance-critical application. I just want to use `std::vector` and make it a bit more cache-friendly.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh! Yeah, I'm glad that I'm getting varied answers.

Comment: Organization of accesses (access by rows and not by columns) should have a greater impact than having consecutively placed rows. 1D arrays instead of vectors of vectors really matters if you have to interface with C language or some library/frameword expecting consecutive data. It can have an impact if you have frequent allocations/deallocations, or if you intend to write a library for general use. But IMHO, simply *make it more cache-friendly* is not a valid reason for adding complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"have heard" together with performance is never the right approach.
To address performance, the golden rule is: Benchmark first!

Also, performance isn't always the most important thing. Typically, you should only optimize for performance if you find that your application isn't fast enough for your purposes. Then, follow these steps:

- First, you need to make sure that the part of the code that you're looking at **is actually a performance bottleneck** in your application (use a profiler for that). No need to optimize something that takes only 1% of your computation time in total - even if you speed it up by a factor of 10, you would only reduce the overall execution time by 0.9%! If you have discovered that this 2D vector access is indeed the bottleneck, then **benchmark** it to have a baseline for future experiments.
- Second, your code needs to be **correct**. No use in it being fast if it is not doing the right thing after you've optimized it for performance. Here I'd recommend to put tests in place (that is, record the results with the naive/unoptimized approach, so that when you optimize, you know if you still get the same result).
- Third, performance optimizations tend to negatively affect **readability** and/or **maintanability** of your code. However, these can be very important, especially for code parts that are critical to be well understood, or that tend to change a lot.

Yes, 2D vectors are an indication that you might have not ideal performance, since as you said, the data is not all in one place.
Yet then again, as you do it curently, the computation of indices done on each access inside of innermost loop also is "expensive".
So, having your data in one large vector instead of a 2D vector field can be faster; especially if you always have to address all elements anyway and don't need "neighbourhood" access, which means that you can simply have one loop iterating from 0 to what you call `getY_AxisLen() * getX_AxisLen()`. Having a benchmark in place, as hinted to above, can help you in finding out which optimizations make sense!
To address the reduced readability/maintanability, it could be helpful in your case to abstract away the actual data structure used for storing the 2D data, so that the actual implementation of how data is stored is hidden from the places where the data is accessed.

Comment: When printing out a few thousand `char`s in the Command Prompt, the for loop takes between 3 to 12 milli seconds. I am quite satisfied with the performance since I have a very old CPU. But I still would like to make it more cache-friendly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when doing a loop which prints the contents, the most significant amount of the time is actually spent in the printing itself, and not in iteration or value retrieval...

Comment: Sorry I meant milli seconds!

Comment: I'd put correctness to the top of the list. Readability helps with that, and the fastest code is no good when it does the wrong thing

Comment: I wouldn't use a vector of vectors for readability. I would just use the proper abstraction for my data, hiding the implementation details.